# Consolidation workbook macro not copying just the range and not pasting to end of list

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that takes information from one workbook and places in another workbook.  It works fine except when I go to another workbook and use it to move items over it pastes over the previous information instead of placing at the bottom of the list.  Also it does not seem to recognize my range and brings information over from below my range.  I am at this time adding this macro to each workbook I need information from if that makes a difference.

```
Sub Copy_With_AutoFilter()

Dim sName As String
Dim My_Range As Range
Dim wsMASTER As Worksheet
Dim shtName As Worksheet
Dim CalcMode As Long
Dim ViewMode As Long
Dim FilterCriteria As String
Dim CCount As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Dim wbSource As Workbook

'Unprotect Sheet
ActiveSheet.Unprotect

'Set filter range on ActiveSheet
Set My_Range = Range("A94:E119")

'Set the sheet
Set wbSource = ThisWorkbook
Set wsMASTER = wbSource.Worksheets("MASTER")

'Set the destination worksheet
Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("A:\Accounting\Manifest Project\Manifest\2014\" & _
                      "Completion Bonus\Summer Bonus.xlsx")

sName = wsMASTER.Range("A1").Value

On Error Resume Next
Set shtName = wbTarget.Worksheets(sName)
On Error GoTo 0

If shtName Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Sheet was not found in target workbook!"
    Exit Sub
End If


'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, .....
With Application
   CalcMode = .Calculation
   .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   .ScreenUpdating = False
   .EnableEvents = False
End With
ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

'Firstly, remove the AutoFilter
My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

'Filter and set the filter field and the filter criteria
My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">0"


'Copy the visible data and use PasteSpecial to paste to the shtName
With My_Range.Parent.AutoFilter.Range
    On Error Resume Next
    'Set rng to the visible cells in My_Range without the header row
    Set rng = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count) _
              .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        'Copy and paste the cells into shtName below the existing data
        rng.Copy
        With shtName.Range("A1" & LastRow(shtName) + 1)
           .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
           .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
           .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
           Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With
    End If
End With
'Protect workbook
wbSource.Protect

'Close AutoFilter
My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
Application.Goto shtName.Range("A1")
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So these are the lines where you paste:

```
    With shtName.Range("A1" & LastRow(shtName) + 1)
       .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
       .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
       .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
```

It should be (I think):

```
    With shtName.Range("A" & (LastRow(shtName) + 1))
       .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
       .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
       .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
```

You told it to paste in "A1." By removing that you will allow it to past in the cell I believe you intended.